# Material UI "Dialog" component opening upon initial page render

Tags: reactjs

I'm using Material UI's "Dialog" component to open a separate mini-form upon a button click event.  However, the Dialog box is actually opening up on page render.  And I'm also unable to close it by clicking the box's "Cancel" button.  Not to mention, whenever I attempt to type in anything into either of the Dialog box's textfields: my client crashes with an error of "TypeError: this.setState is not a function" for the line of:  onChange={(e) => this.setState({ playlistName: e.target.value })}

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import FormLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormLabel';
import FormControlLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import { makeStyles, withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { DataGrid } from '@material-ui/data-grid';
import Footer from './Footer';
import theme from '../../styles/MuiTheme';
import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem';
import ListItemAvatar from '@material-ui/core/ListItemAvatar';
import ListItemIcon from '@material-ui/core/ListItemIcon';
import ListItemText from '@material-ui/core/ListItemText';
import Avatar from '@material-ui/core/Avatar';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import FormGroup from '@material-ui/core/FormGroup';
import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox'
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import DeleteIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Delete';
import EditIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Edit';
import ListItemSecondaryAction from '@material-ui/core/ListItemSecondaryAction';
import QueueMusicIcon from '@material-ui/icons/QueueMusic';
import Dialog from '@material-ui/core/Dialog';
import DialogActions from '@material-ui/core/DialogActions';
import DialogContent from '@material-ui/core/DialogContent';
import DialogContentText from '@material-ui/core/DialogContentText';
import DialogTitle from '@material-ui/core/DialogTitle';

const styles = theme => ({
    root: {
        flexGrow: 1,
        '& > *': {
            margin: theme.spacing(1),
            width: '25ch',
            maxWidth: 752
        },
        control: {
            padding: theme.spacing(2)
        },
        button: {
            primary: "#1DB954"
        },
        listAllPlaylists: {
            backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
            overflow: "auto",
            maxHeight: "10"
        },
        title: {
            margin: theme.spacing(4, 0, 2)
        }
    }
});

function generate(element) {
    return [0].map((value) =>
        React.cloneElement(element, {
            key: value
        }),
    );
}

class EditPlaylistDetails extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            artist: '',
            album: '',
            song: '',
            playlistName: '',
            description: '',
            playlistData: [],
            allPlaylists: [],
            open: false,
            secondary: false
        }
        // this.displayExistingPlaylists = this.displayExistingPlaylists.bind(this);
        // this.displayLivePlaylistData = this.displayLivePlaylistData.bind(this);
        this.editModal = this.editModal.bind(this)
        this.handlePlaylistDelete = this.handlePlaylistDelete.bind(this)
        this.handlePlaylistEdit = this.handlePlaylistEdit.bind(this)
        this.handleClickOpen = this.handleClickOpen.bind(this)
        this.handleClose = this.handleClose.bind(this)

    };

    handleSecondary = () => {
        this.setState({ secondary: true });
    };

    // handleDense = () => {
    //     this.setState({ dense: true });
    // };

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('http://localhost:5040/playlist/', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: new Headers({
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': this.props.sessionToken
            })
        }).then((response) => response.json())
            .then((res) => {
                console.log(res);
                return res;
            }).then((res) => {
                this.setState({
                    allPlaylists: res,
                    playlistData: res
                })

            })
            .catch((err) => { console.log(err) })
    };


    handlePlaylistDelete(playlistDeleteId, userId) {
        console.log(playlistDeleteId)
        fetch(`http://localhost:5040/playlist/delete/${playlistDeleteId}`, {
            method: 'DELETE',
            body: JSON.stringify({
                playlist: {
                    playlistId: this.props.playlistIdProp,
                    playlistName: this.state.playlistName,
                    description: this.state.description
                }
            }),
            headers: new Headers({
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': this.props.sessionToken
            })
        })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
    };

    handlePlaylistEdit(playlistUpdateId) {
        playlistUpdateId.preventDefault();

        fetch(`http://localhost:5040/playlist/update/${playlistUpdateId}`, {
            method: 'PUT',
            body: JSON.stringify({
                playlist: {
                    playlistId: this.props.playlistIdProp,
                    playlistName: this.state.playlistName,
                    description: this.state.description
                }
            }),
            headers: new Headers({
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': this.props.sessionToken
            })
        }).then(
            (response) => response.json()
        ).then((allPlaylistsResponse) => {
            console.log(this.state.open)
        });
    };

    editModal(playlistId) {
        return (
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={() => this.handlePlaylistEdit(playlistId)} noValidate autoComplete="off" style={{ marginTop: '2rem' }}>
                    <TextField size="small" id="outlined-basic standard-size-small" label="Artist / Band" variant="filled" style={{ backgroundColor: 'white', color: 'white', borderRadius: '10px' }} onChange={(e) => this.setState({ artist: e.target.value })} value={this.state.artist} />

                    <TextField size="small" id="outlined-basic standard-size-small" label="Album" variant="filled" style={{ backgroundColor: 'white', color: 'white', borderRadius: '10px' }} onChange={(e) => this.setState({ album: e.target.value })} value={this.state.album} />

                    <TextField size="small" id="outlined-basic standard-size-small" label="Song" variant="filled" style={{ backgroundColor: 'white', color: 'white', borderRadius: '10px' }} onChange={(e) => this.setState({ song: e.target.value })} value={this.state.song} />
                    <br />
                    <Button variant="contained" color="primary" type="submit">Add Info to Playlist</Button>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    };

    handleClickOpen() {
        this.setState = ({
            open: true
        })
    };

    handleClose() {
        this.setState = ({
            open: false
        })
    };


    render() {
        const { classes } = this.props;
        return (

            <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                <div style={{ width: '100%', marginTop: '80px' }}>

                    <h1>View / Edit Your Created Playlists:</h1>
                    {/* <div >
                        {this.displayExistingPlaylists()}
                    </div> */}
                    <Grid container direction="column" alignContent="center" spacing={2} className={this.props.classes.root}>
                        <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
                            <div style={{ textAlign: "-webkit-center", maxHeight: 400, overflow: 'auto' }}>
                                {this.state.allPlaylists.map((allPlaylistsCreated, index) => {
                                    console.log(this.state.allPlaylists)
                                    console.log(allPlaylistsCreated)
                                    const { classes } = this.props;
                                    return (
                                        <Grid key={index} item xs={12} md={6} style={{ maxHeight: '100px', overflow: 'auto', textAlign: "center" }}>
                                            <div className={classes.listAllPlaylists}>
                                                <List>
                                                    {generate(
                                                        <ListItem>
                                                            <ListItemAvatar>
                                                                <Avatar>
                                                                    <QueueMusicIcon key={index} style={{ color: "#191414" }} />
                                                                </Avatar>
                                                            </ListItemAvatar>
                                                            <ListItemText
                                                                key={index}
                                                                primary={allPlaylistsCreated.playlistName}
                                                                secondary={allPlaylistsCreated.description}
                                                                style={{ color: "white" }}
                                                            />
                                                            <ListItemSecondaryAction>
                                                                <IconButton edge="start" aria-label="edit">
                                                                    <EditIcon key={index} style={{ color: "#1DB954" }} onClick={this.handleClickOpen(allPlaylistsCreated.id)} />
                                                                </IconButton>
                                                                <IconButton edge="end" aria-label="delete">
                                                                    <DeleteIcon key={index} style={{ color: "red" }} onClick={() => this.handlePlaylistDelete(allPlaylistsCreated.id, allPlaylistsCreated.userId)} />
                                                                </IconButton>
                                                            </ListItemSecondaryAction>
                                                        </ListItem>
                                                    )}
                                                </List>
                                            </div>
                                        </Grid>

                                    )
                                })}

                            </div>
                        </Grid>

                    </Grid>
                    <form onSubmit={this.handlePlaylistEdit}>
                        <Dialog open={this.handleClickOpen} onClose={this.handleClose}>
                            <DialogTitle>Update Playlist Details:</DialogTitle>
                            <DialogContent>
                                <DialogContentText>
                                    You may update your playlist information below:
                                </DialogContentText>
                                <TextField
                                    margin='dense'
                                    id='playlistName'
                                    label='Playlist Name:'
                                    fullWidth
                                    onChange={(e) => this.setState({ playlistName: e.target.value })}
                                    value={this.state.playlistName}
                                    required
                                />
                                <br />
                                <TextField
                                    margin='dense'
                                    id='description'
                                    label='Description:'
                                    fullWidth
                                    onChange={(e) => this.setState({ description: e.target.value })}
                                    value={this.state.description}
                                />
                            </DialogContent>
                            <DialogActions>
                                <Button onClick={this.handleClose} color='primary'>
                                    Cancel
                                    </Button>
                                <Button onClick={this.handlePlaylistEdit} color='primary'>
                                    Update Playlist
                                    </Button>
                            </DialogActions>
                        </Dialog>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </ThemeProvider >
        )
    }
}

export default withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true })(EditPlaylistDetails);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

syntax is wrong for setState

```
  handleClickOpen() {
    this.setState ({
      open: true
    })
  }

  handleClose() {
    this.setState({
      open: false
    })
  }
```

also correct below open value binding to {this.state.open}

```
<Dialog open={this.state.open}  .... />
```

You are passing something for handleClickOpen() method, but not accepting any parameter in function definition.

```
<EditIcon key={index} style={{ color: "#1DB954" }} onClick={this.handleClickOpen(**allPlaylistsCreated.id**)} />
```